# carousel trouble implementing bootstrap script

Tags: html, css, carousel

Currently, my carousel pictures are stacking vertically, and the HTML and CSS is not really the problem.

It seems as though, whenever I actually implement

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

the actual carousel works, and is situated and working properly, however the rest of my document completely changes, basically ignoring my initial CSS I have done up specifically for this html page.

Is there anyway that I can actually implement

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

the code to actually make the carousel work, while making sure that it does not change any of my CSS that I have initially?

Comment: Try to change the order of your CSS, first load bootstrap and than your own css. Else give us more detail of whats inside your `<head></head>`

Comment: can you see your code...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Like user C Travel said, try to change the order of your `<link>` inside your `<head></head>` tag. You need to make sure that your custom CSS file is loaded AFTER bootsrap's main CSS file.

Comment: That worked! Thankyou so much!